# event Action Invoke from different thread in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, events, action

```
public class A
{
    private B NotifyObj = new B();
    
    public A()
    {
        NotifyObj.NotifyEvent += Notified;
    }
     private async void Notified()
     {
         
     }
    
}

Class B
{
   public event Action NotifyEvent;

   public CallEvent()
   {
       NotifyEvent?.Invoke();
   }
}
```

In the above code(using C# WPF) class A is running in main thread and Class B is running in separate thread. What would happen if main thread is busy and other thread call CallEvent(). Is it going to get queue in the message queue or it will stop current execution and execute this then continue the previous execution. Basically does NotifyEvent?.Invoke() work like Postmessage/SendMessage in C++

Comment: You have a misunderstanding as to how threads work. When you say "class A is running in main thread and Class B is running in separate thread" that's not true. You might have instantiated them in separate threads, but they don't run on a different thread. What matters is the thread that you use when you call methods on the instances. You could create a third thread and call methods on those instances and it'll use the third thread the whole time.

Comment: I know how threads work. I just used that to explain the scenario. My focus is what happens when a busy thread receives an event Action from another thread.

Comment: "a busy thread receives an event Action from another thread" - that's what I'm saying - threads don't work that way. You don't seem to know how threads work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the method is called from a separate thread, it will be executed on the separate thread.

If your need is to force the main thread (if not busy) to run some code, for example for handling the UI, you can check `Dispatcher.Invoke` method.

Comment: So Notified() is executed in the same thread where  NotifyEvent?.Invoke() is called?

Comment: It should, but you can try it in vs if you put a break point in the call back and check the  current thread

Comment: event.invoke() handler gets executed in the same thread as event.invoke()